# How To Add Event Listener To HTML5 Video Poster Image Load Event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Is it possible?

I would like to attach an event listener to the poster image on HTML5 video element in order to run a code once the poster image is loaded and displayed.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this but I need help.

Comment: Once the poster image is loaded is loadedmetadata event fired?

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```js
var poster = $( 'video' ).prop( 'poster' );
if ( poster ) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        alert( 'load' );
    };
    image.src = poster;
}
```