# Event on video poster loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

I've found a problem.

I have a video element in modal dialog, with poster image setup.
After I open a modal, the poster is not fully loaded, so the dialog is not bigger than screen, so modal is not scrollable. After poster image is loaded, modal will stretch but it does not trigger event that should recount if modal should be scrollable.

I thought about some event on video poster load, but did not find something like that. How would you solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Add Event Listener To HTML5 Video Poster Image Load Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571424/how-to-add-event-listener-to-html5-video-poster-image-load-event)

Answer (score 3):

Hey good catch about this missing event.

What I would do : preload the image with an `<img>` element and wait for its loadevent.

```js
snippet.log('before:  '+video.getBoundingClientRect().width)
var img = new Image();
img.src = video.getAttribute('poster');
img.onload = function(){snippet.log('loaded: '+video.getBoundingClientRect().width);}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<video id="video" poster="http://lorempixel.com/800/300"></video>
```

Comment: I will try something and let you know :)

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a duplicate question. What was not working then in the solution given there ?

Comment: So, the thing is this works, but it will trigger for every video tag on the page whether or not i've displayed the modal. It would be better to trigger event only for that video, on that modal, but I will figure it out :)

Comment: well simply wrap it into your modal function : `function createModal(element){
var poster = element.getAttribute('poster');
if(poster){ var img = new Image(); img.onload = showModal;} else showModal();}`