# display loading indicator until component (and its child components) are loaded

Tags: angular

I've got a component `app-show-on-event` that shows when some event happens. When the event happens `showThisComponent` in parent component is set to `true`. Take a look

parent.component.html

```
<app-show-on-event *ngIf="showThisComponent"></app-show-on-event>
```

Show on event component has a ton of child and grand child components. Many of them contain `video` elements. I'd like to show a `loading indicator` in place of `app-show-on-event` component until at least posters for videos are loaded.

What solution do you recommend?

Note: I am not using a router.

Comment: Do you have any indication of when the children of `app-show-on-event` are ready?

Comment: Currently no. I am not using JS to load to the  videos. instead. I just use 
<video *ngFor="ng for data here" [src]="path" [poster]="path2">. Thanks. I'll google how to listen to poster load event.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571424/how-to-add-event-listener-to-html5-video-poster-image-load-event) seems to have a solution on how to listen for poster laod event. If you can get that information, you can simply show a loading bar until the event happens

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable like

```
loader:boolean = false;
```

after showThisComponent becomes true change loader value to true like

```
this.loader = true;
```

html looks like

`<img src="path" *ngIf="loader == false">`

or simply

```
<img src="path ro loader gif image"*ngIf="!showThisComponent">
```

the loader image shows untill showcomponent becomes true

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```js
export class ChildrenComponent implements OnInit {

  loaded = false;
  @Output('loadedContent') loadedEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaded = ApiForContents().then(() => {
      this.emitLoaded(true);
    });
    // if you want to catch error
  }
  
  emitLoaded(bool: boolean) {
    this.loadedEvent.emit(bool);
  }

}

export class ParentComponent {

  spinner = true;
  
  stopSpinner() {
    this.spinner = false;
  }
  
  isLoading() {
    return this.spinner;
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- parent HTML -->

<spinner *ngIf="isLoading()"></spinner>
<children (loadedContent)="stopSpinner()">...</children>
```

Comment: stopSpinner() will always return false. Hence, on initial load, isLoading() will be called and spinner will show, but after that for subsequent child loads, it won't display. thoughts?